# Mute a youtube video for website background

Tags: jquery, html, css, video, youtube

I have a website that I'd like to use a full width video on. I previously had it fully working but randomly the once muted video plays sound. I haven't touched the code at all from when it was working (no sound) until now. I checked on the tutorial I got the code from and the sound is also unmuted there, so I'm curious if its a youtube thing.

Here is the link of the tutorial: 
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/ful-screen-video-background

this is where it *should* be muted, in the anchor tag within the data-property is **mute:true**

```
<section class="content-section video-section">
  <div class="pattern-overlay">
  <a id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdJc1_IBKJA',containment:'.video-section', quality:'large', autoPlay:true, mute:true, opacity:1}">bg</a>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>Full Width Video</h1>  
        <h3>Enjoy Adding Full Screen Videos to your Page Sections</h3>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried using **muted:true** instead because I can across that in a google search but it does nothing as well, all other searches say **mute:true** should work, can anyone see an issue with this? or know of another way to mute the sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this [library](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Awesome-Video-Background-Plugin-with-HTML5-Youtube-API-YTPlayer.html) . It is having option for **MUTE** and other awesome features are also there.

Answer (score 0):

You got this [library](https://github.com/florianchapon/youtube-background) as well. You only have to include the js file and call the function like this for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    ytbg("vQWlNALvbhE", 0, 17, 1);
});
```

as an explanation:

```
ytbg("video link", starttime, endtime, volume).
```